# Building and Editing Android kernel in, Eclipse with development studio 5 plugin

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, build, kernel

I have downloaded eclipse DS-5 from this site

http://ds.arm.com/downloads/

I was also able to disassemble basic c program code.

But the code can be disassembled using DS-5, only after successfully building the c source code and the respective binary for the C source code is generated.

So now I have to successfully build the android kernel in eclipse before am able to use the DS-5 disassembler tools.

I found a site which explains building Linux kernel in eclipse 
http://financecoding.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/building-and-editing-linux-kernel-in-eclipse-for-android-rowboat/

The above link is for building linux kernel in eclipse, can anyone please give a link to build android kernel in eclipse or please elaborate the steps to build android kernel in eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully hacked and built android from Eclipse CDT!

I have used [this site](http://kloggsays.blogspot.pt/2011/06/kernel-development-using-eclipse-omap4.html) as a reference to Eclipse configuration for android kernel, which refers to an old revision of a generic kernel configuration tutorial that can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php?title=HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source&oldid=296728).

Remember that the first build has to be done from the shell, in order to create the .config and some other stuff.

Next, you will get "Type xyz could not be resolved" errors, but this is due to a [bug in Eclipse Indexer](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351549) that still isn't fixed in the latest build. The workaround to this is to switch code-analysis off in Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code analysis , but I recommend to disable *only* the Mal-functioning features, which in my case were "Symbol is not resolved" and "Type cannot be resolved".

Hope this helps, have fun hacking the kernel !